# Displaying duplicate results in arraylist java

Tags: java, jdbc, arraylist

I am using JDBC to run a SQL query in Java. I want to take the result of the query and store it in an arraylist so that I can display the data in a graph of some sort. I'm getting the same line printing out the same number of times as `columnCount`. Here is my code.

```
ArrayList <String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
int columnCount = rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        if(rset!=null)
        {
            while(rset.next())
            {
                found=true;

                String[] row = new String[columnCount];
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                    row[i] = rset.getString(i + 1);                    
                    row[i] = rset.getString("Date") + " "
                            + rset.getString("Hour");
                    System.out.println(row[i]);
                }
                result.add(row); 
        }
```

Comment: it seems your code needs debug!

Comment: Why the `String[]`? Wouldn't it be better with a class? `class Row { private String value; private Date date; /* getters and setters */}`. Why also getting date and hour for each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `row[i]` rewrites the value of the column. Just remove it and you'll see your records:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    row[i] = rset.getString(i + 1);                    
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
result.add(row);
...
```